# ANDROID - How to access another class from a different Class?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a `MapView.java` wherein it requests for SMS permission, Location permission etc. I created a new Java class for the `SMSReceiver`, which extends `BroadcastReceiver` and has an `onReceive` method.

The problem is, I am struggling with how I will call the `SMSReceiver` class to my `MapView.Java`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You will have to pass SMSReceiver class using Intent.

Comment: You just have to register your SMSReceiver in your MapView class. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out.**

Hope it will help!

```
registerReceiver(mySMSBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION));
```

Comment: It says "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo"

Comment: Provide full log.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.coni, PID: 1081
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.coni/com.example.sample.MapView}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.View.getContext()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.coni.MapView.onCreate(MapView.java:127)

Comment: For clarification, I declared View view on MapView class. Is that right?

Comment: I need to see class.

Comment: I commented the MapView class below.

Comment: <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"  android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Is that the proper way of declaring the receiver to the manifest? Sorry Sir, I am new to Android programming. Thank you for your time.

Comment: registerReceiver(mySMSBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION)); try it out

Comment: Thank you. Figured it out. :)